# No puedo imprimir el resultado 'operand type(s) for -: 'type' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x

*Trate de cambiara el nombre de la variable, crear otra variable para resolver los parentesis y me sigue saliendo ese error*

```
celsius = int
far     = int
kelvin  = int

print("Bienvenido!")


#Introduccion de datos
menu = int(input("""Introduce Una Opcion De Conversion
  
  1. De Celsius ℃ a Farenheit ℉
  2. De Celsius ℃ a Kelvin °K
  3. De Farenheit ℉ a Celsius ℃
  4. De Kelvin °K a Celsius ℃
  
 Introdusca Una Opcion : """))

if    menu == 1 :
  celsius = int(input("\nIngrese la temperatura en grados Celsius :"))
elif  menu == 2 :
  celsius = int(input("\nIngrese la temperatura en grados Celsius :"))
elif  menu == 3:
  far   = int(input("\nIngrese la temperatura en grados Farenheit :"))
elif  menu == 4:
  kelvin  = int(input("\nIngrese la temperatura en grados Kelvin :"))
else :
  print("Introdusca un numero valido")

#calculos y print final

CaF = (celsius * 9 / 5) + 32
FaC = (far - 32) * 5 / 39
CaK = celsius + 273.15
KaC = kelvin - 273.15

if    menu == 1 :
  print(f"\n{celsius} grados Celsius equivalen a {CaF} Farenheit")
elif  menu == 2 :
  print(f"\n{celsius} grados Celsius equivalen a {CaK} Kelvin")
elif  menu == 3:
  print(f"\n{far} grados Farenheit equivalen a {FaC} Celsius")
elif  menu == 4:
  print(f"\n{kelvin} grados Kelvin equivalen a {KaC} Celsius")
```

**Error**

[image: Este es el error]

*Perdón si es algo super básico llevo poco aprendiendo y llevo mas de 2 horas tratando de resolver el código, si me pudieran explicar en que es lo que falle se los agradecería demaciado*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te agrego la solución al final.

Antes de ello, explicarte porque te arroja ese error:

Resulta que el sistema que estas haciendo, esta trabajando de una sola corrida. Para ponerte en contexto, el usuario solo puede elegir 1 opción, entonces solo se tiene que hacer un calculo no varios como lo estas haciendo.

Imagínate que el usuario elige la opción `1. De Celsius ℃ a Farenheit ℉`

```
CaF = (celsius * 9 / 5) + 32
FaC = (far - 32) * 5 / 39
CaK = celsius + 273.15
KaC = kelvin - 273.15
```

Entonces en el calculo, se procesa `CaF`, porque si tienes el valor de celcius que te dio el usuario. En cambio cuando va a hacer el calculo de `FaC` no lo puede hacer, porque tu variable `far` es un tipo de dato que no tiene valor, ya que el usuario no ingresa ese valor. Y así mismo pasaría con los calculos para `CaK` y `KaC`.

Entonces la solución es definir estas variables globales (`CaF, FaC, CaK,  KaC`) y procesar el calculo dentro de las opciones que pones. Aquí la solución:

```
celsius = int
far     = int
kelvin  = int
CaF = 0
CaK = 0
KaC = 0


print("Bienvenido!")

#Introduccion de datos
menu = int(input("""Introduce Una Opcion De Conversion
  
  1. De Celsius ℃ a Farenheit ℉
  2. De Celsius ℃ a Kelvin °K
  3. De Farenheit ℉ a Celsius ℃
  4. De Kelvin °K a Celsius ℃
  
 Introdusca Una Opcion : """))

if    menu == 1 :
  celsius = int(input("\nIngrese la temperatura en grados Celsius :"))
  CaF = (celsius * 9 / 5) + 32
elif  menu == 2 :
  celsius = int(input("\nIngrese la temperatura en grados Celsius :"))
  CaK = celsius + 273.15
elif  menu == 3:
  far   = int(input("\nIngrese la temperatura en grados Farenheit :"))
  FaC = (far - 32) * 5 / 39
elif  menu == 4:
  kelvin  = int(input("\nIngrese la temperatura en grados Kelvin :"))
  KaC = kelvin - 273.15
else :
  print("Introdusca un numero valido")

#calculos y print final

if    menu == 1 :
  print(f"\n{celsius} grados Celsius equivalen a {CaF} Farenheit")
elif  menu == 2 :
  print(f"\n{celsius} grados Celsius equivalen a {CaK} Kelvin")
elif  menu == 3:
  print(f"\n{far} grados Farenheit equivalen a {FaC} Celsius")
elif  menu == 4:
  print(f"\n{kelvin} grados Kelvin equivalen a {KaC} Celsius")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias de igual forma, tu solucion tambien me gusto y me ayudo ha aplicar un poco mas la logica

Answer (score 0):

El error esta en que asignas el tipo int a tus variables:

```
celsius = int
far     = int
kelvin  = int
```

Y que despues intentas restar de ellos aún cuando tu `if` ramificó sólo por una via:

```
CaF = (celsius * 9 / 5) + 32
FaC = (far - 32) * 5 / 39
CaK = celsius + 273.15
KaC = kelvin - 273.15
```

Cambia el inicio:

```
celsius = 1
far     = 1
kelvin  = 1
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias no llegue a pensarlo asi ty

Comment: Si te sirvió acepta la respuesta como correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

El problema es porque al definir tus variables estas utilizando `int` que en realidad es solo el tipo de variable pero no un valor

```
celsius = int
far     = int
kelvin  = int
```

Entonces al hacer tus cálculos hay variables que no tienen valor, que solo tienen `int` y por lo tanto no puedes utilizar el operador `-`. Si eliges cualquiera de las opciones de conversión entonces hay por lo menos otras 2 variables que no tienen valor. Por ejemplo, si eliges `CaF` entonces `far` y `kelvin` no tendrían valor

```
CaF = (celsius * 9 / 5) + 32
FaC = (far - 32) * 5 / 39
CaK = celsius + 273.15
KaC = kelvin - 273.15
```

Por cierto, es mejor utilizar `float` porque vas a hacer divisiones

El código completo funcionando sería así:

```
celsius = 0.0
far     = 0.0
kelvin  = 0.0

print("Bienvenido!")


#Introduccion de datos
menu = int(input("""Introduce Una Opcion De Conversion
  
  1. De Celsius ℃ a Farenheit ℉
  2. De Celsius ℃ a Kelvin °K
  3. De Farenheit ℉ a Celsius ℃
  4. De Kelvin °K a Celsius ℃
  
 Introdusca Una Opcion : """))

if    menu == 1 :
  celsius = float(input("\nIngrese la temperatura en grados Celsius :"))
elif  menu == 2 :
  celsius = float(input("\nIngrese la temperatura en grados Celsius :"))
elif  menu == 3:
  far   = float(input("\nIngrese la temperatura en grados Farenheit :"))
elif  menu == 4:
  kelvin  = float(input("\nIngrese la temperatura en grados Kelvin :"))
else :
  print("Introdusca un numero valido")

#calculos y print final

CaF = (celsius * 9 / 5) + 32
FaC = (far - 32) * 5 / 39
CaK = celsius + 273.15
KaC = kelvin - 273.15


if    menu == 1 :
  print(f"\n{celsius} grados Celsius equivalen a {CaF} Farenheit")
elif  menu == 2 :
  print(f"\n{celsius} grados Celsius equivalen a {CaK} Kelvin")
elif  menu == 3:
  print(f"\n{far} grados Farenheit equivalen a {FaC} Celsius")
elif  menu == 4:
  print(f"\n{kelvin} grados Kelvin equivalen a {KaC} Celsius")
```